# How to configure format of timestamp in Postman?

Tags: json, postman, datetime-format

I've got the latest version of Postman for Windows (6.3.0 at the moment). 
Somehow it now returns timestamps as a number of Unix seconds (like this `1852502400.000`) instead of DateTime in format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.sss]Z`.

Server-side is microservice written in Java, type of the field is java.time.OffsetDateTime.

Is there something in Postman I should configure, or is it depends from server implementation?

Comment: How is the data being serialized to json by the java program?

Answer (score 12):

You can always use javascript to help you with this.
Make use of the environment variable and add the variable in place of the `{{$timestamp}}` in your request.

In your pre-request script do this:

```
let timestamp = new Date().toJSON();
pm.environment.set('timestamp', timestamp);
```

Now, wherever in your request that you were using `{{$timestamp}}` replace it with `{{timestamp}}`.

Just run the request and you'll get the date in this format: `"2018-09-13T18:41:02.363Z"`

---

*Additonal information:*
Postman also has [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/) builtin. So you can make use of that too.

Danny Dainton has written a great blog on how to use momentjs inside postman: https://dannydainton.com/2018/05/21/hold-on-wait-a-moment/ !

Postman sandbox API reference: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference

Comment: I don't understand _why_ `toJSON()` works at all, but it certainly seems to produce a ISO 8601-compliant date! Thanks for the tip. Why Postman (or JavaScript in general) call this a "JSON date" is quite mysterious to me; do you have some pointers to documentation about that choice? The best I could find was the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$isoTimestamp` variable in postman